# Как сделать, чтобы не было дырки , если нет итема?

Tags: html, css

если во втором ряду не будет третьего элемента - то будет справа пустое место

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.item {
  min-height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.column-1 {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.column-2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.column-3 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item column-1">1</div>
  <div class="item column-1">2</div>
  <div class="item column-2">3</div>
  <div class="item column-2">4</div>
  <div class="item column-2">5</div>
  <div class="item column-3">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Объясните конкретнее, в чем проблема, потому что если я понял правильно, у вас при удалении из HTML символа "5" пропадает ячейка, но у меня все отображается нормально

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k501az2n/3/

Comment: вот, я об этом. справа пустое место. Удалил 5 и 6 элемент

Comment: никак это не исправить на гридах, идет жесткая привязка, пользуйтесь флексом, чтобы избежать этого

Comment: может через чайлды как то?

Comment: [почитайте тут](https://coderoad.ru/46276793/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-CSS)

Comment: Не понятно, почему вопрос сформулирован как какой-то частный случай. Для частного случая можно придумать селектор, которой переопределит общее правило. А вообще заполнять "дырки" в grid-контейнере часто помогает `grid-auto-flow: row dense;` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow